# Flutter check file exist in ApplicationDocumentsDirectory

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How i check existence of file and directory  in ApplicationDocumentsDirectory before download it ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

String fileName = "file.jpg";
String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
String savePath = '$dir/$fileName';

//for directories: await Directory(savePath).exists();
if (await File(savePath).exists()) {
    print("File exists");        
} else {
    print("File doesn't exist");
}
```